# Bundle Product add to cart as individual line items

Tags: magento, bundle, product

Is it possible to have a bundle product that when added to the cart adds each of the bundle items as individual line items.
I want to allow my customers to configure their product (let’s say it’s a computer) and then in the shopping cart, remove an item they don't want - or change their mind about - from that bundle. They might then choose to add a new item instead - or a bunch of other (non-bundle stuff, just normal shopping).
The idea being that they have a fast method of adding most of the stuff they want in this bundle, but they can then edit their cart to add something that wasn’t available as an option to them when configuring the bundle.
I don’t want to overload the user with too many options in the bundle product page.

I might have missed an option in Magento, but currently it adds all the bundle items into the caret as a single line item, making it uneditable in the way I want.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Voting up because of the potential usefulness for this. Would make many shipping configurations much simpler to deal with if the cart was all just single line items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior in Magento is intentional, as you may not want to let a customer order a PC without a CPU or memory. In your case, this assumption appears not to be the case, but that remains the method for using bundled products.

There are a few options open to you to avoid this situation. Firstly, you could use some product type other than bundle, and actually add simple products to your cart rather than the bundled ones. This would allow customers to add options at will, but would not preserve any promotional pricing on the products, as Magento checks those prices/discounts on every page load, and would kick out any changes you set manually.

The other option would be to allow customers an easier path to changing the bundle product that they have chosen. When rendering the bundle product, you could render a little X button (or whatever you find appropriate), which would lead to an action you specify, whose job it is to change the bundle options, resave the cart item, and redirect the user back to the cart. This is probably the cleanest solution to the problem.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thanks for the info Joe.
Do you know if it is possible to edit the display of a "grouped" product instead, so that it could be displayed in the same way as the bundle product is (section heading then product selections) rather than one big clupm of products one after the other?
I am assuming here that grouped products are added to the cart as single line items - this may not be the case either?